# Wordpress admin search not returning results for custom post type with custom fields

Tags: wordpress

So I defined a custom post type of type 'Clients' with custom fields as follows:

```
// Clients
register_post_type( 'isa_client',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Clients' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Client' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => 'mnuIsAppointments',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'supports' => array('thumbnail') 
    )
);
```

and also specified which columns to show on the admin clients page as follows:

```
add_filter("manage_edit-isa_client_columns", "isa_client_edit_columns"); 

function isa_client_custom_columns($column){  
        global $post;  
        switch ($column)  
        {  
            case "isa_client_salutation":  
                $custom = get_post_custom();  
                echo "<b><a href=" . get_edit_post_link($post->id) . ">" . $custom["isa_client_salutation"][0] . " " . $custom["isa_client_name"][0] . " " . $custom["isa_client_surname"][0] . "</a></b>";
                break; 
            case "isa_client_phone":  
                $custom = get_post_custom();  
                echo $custom["isa_client_phone"][0];
                break; 
            case "isa_client_email":  
                $custom = get_post_custom();  
                echo $custom["isa_client_email"][0];
                break; 
            case "isa_client_address":  
                $custom = get_post_custom();  
                echo $custom["isa_client_address"][0];
                break; 
        }  
}
```

However when trying to search for a client using a custom field value I am not getting any results